Merge laravel component background color with custom tailwind color not working
I am trying to overwrite the background color of a laravel component with a custom color setup in tailwind:
<x-button id="book_but" onclick="book()" class="bg-accent">
    Book
</x-button>

The code for the component looks like this component:
<button {{$attributes->merge([
    'class' => 'py-2 px-4 text-white rounded-lg bg-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-600',
    'type' => 'submit'
    ])}}
>
    <x-text>
        {{$slot}}
    </x-text>
</button>

I include tailwind through cdn and define the new color in the header:
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<script>
    tailwind.config = {
        theme: {
            extend: {
                colors: {        
                    accent: "{{config('colors.accent')}}",
                },
            },
        },
    };
</script>

The added color accent works fine when called in usual HTML elements (class="bg-accent") and it even works in components that do not have a default background color.
It just seems to get ignored in case the component does set a default value. I can over write the default value of the component with a "standard" tailwind color (e.g. bg-red-500 works when overwriting default color).
I tried adding the color to the tailwind safelist:
tailwind.config = {
    theme: {
        extend: {
            colors: {        
                accent: "{{config('colors.accent')}}",
            },
        },
    },
    safelist: [
        'bg-accent',
    ],
};

but that does not help.
I tried using the hex color directly (bg-[#ffa500]) and this gives the same issue, also when it is safelisted.

You can use inspect to see how component class will be merged. From your code, the button component will look like this
<button class="py-2 px-4 text-white rounded-lg bg-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-600 bg-accent" type="submit" >

I think that if there is two background class, then it will take the last one on the compiled CSS.
To force the background color, you can use important modifier ('!') like this
<x-button id="book_but" onclick="book()" class="!bg-accent">


Adding the ! indeed sets the color to accent finally! Thank you for this suggestion! However the true issue still does not seem resolved.
If I use a default tailwind color red-500 like so:
<button class="py-2 px-4 text-white rounded-lg bg-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-600 bg-red-500" type="submit" >
The button does appear red, no ! needed.
